# Data table in lwc not showing columns

Tags: lightning-web-components, javascript, lightning-datatable, fieldsets

I have created a LWC component that uses datatable and for columns I am using fieldset. I am calling an apex class that will give me fieldset and I am pushing data in array of object that I am using in html.

Here's the js

export default class customcmp extends LightningElement {

```
@api recordId;
@track fieldSet = [];
fieldSetToShow = [];
@track data = [];

connectedCallback(){ 
    getFieldSet().then(result=>{  
        this.fieldSet =  JSON.parse(result)  
        for(let i in this.fieldSet){
            if(this.fieldSet[i].type != "reference"){
                var option=
                { 
                    label:this.fieldSet[i].label,
                    fieldName:this.fieldSet[i].fieldPath,
                    type:this.fieldSet[i].type,
                    typeApex:this.fieldSet[i].typeApex,
                };
                this.fieldSetToShow.push(option);
            } 
        } 
        console.log('fieldSetToShow'+JSON.stringify(this.fieldSetToShow));
    })
}
```

}

Here's the html

```
    <lightning-datatable 
            key-field="id"
            data={data}
            columns={fieldSetToShow}
            >
    </lightning-datatable>
```

but when I assign fieldSetToShow to some other array and use that in my html the columns becomes visible. I am not able to figure out the concept behind it. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: make sure that your data and column keys have the same casing, Javascript is case sensitive, so if one column key starts with a capitalized letter, but the data keys don'tt, your table won't render data.

Comment: okay i will keep that in mind but as of now i am not able to see the columns.

Answer (score 2):

You did not @track the property, and you didn't update the variable's object reference, so LWC doesn't detect any changes. There's two ways to fix this.

## @track

```
@track fieldSetToShow = [];
```

This tells LWC to check the variable for changes every time. This is a performance sink, so it's recommended you keep this to a minimum.

## Update Object Reference

The preferred form is to make sure that `oldValue !== newValue`, which deals with copying the object somehow. In this case, instead of `Array.prototype.push` to build the array, you can use `Array.prototype.filter` and `Array.prototype.map`:

```
this.fieldSetToShow = JSON.parse(result)
    .filter(field => field.type != 'reference') // if(fieldSet.type != 'reference') ...
    .map(field => ({label: field.label, fieldName: field.fieldPath, type: field.type, typeApex: field.typeApex}));
```

As a general rule, whenever you have `for(...) someVar.push(...)`, you can use `Array.prototype.map` instead, which also satisfies the rule that `oldValue !== newValue`, which will cause a render cycle to occur.

---

I recommend that you study [Array](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array) on MDN. It's a much more functional object than basic tutorials will have you believe. There's rarely ever a need for a for loop with arrays.

Comment: Thanks for looking into this. I have now made fieldSetToShow as a track variable but still I am not able to see the columns even in logs i can see data of fieldSetToShow by stringify this array but its not visible on html side.

Comment: @DeepanshuRajta The variable name was wrong in my example code.